# Difference in meaning between gerund and infinitive

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

> 1. The whole class was working hard preparing for the exam.
> 2. The whole class was working hard to prepare for the exam.

What are the differences between these two sentences?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. What does your research show?

Comment: _Preparing for the exam_ was what their work consisted of. _To prepare_ was the reason why they were working so hard.

Comment: The first sentence has a gerund complement governed by _work_. The second sentence has a purpose infinitive (not a complement). Since the gerund complement of _work_ describes the work being done, this turns out to be the same as the purpose infinitive, with **this** verb. But not necessarily with any other verb.